# Passing form data with UnCSS

Tags: javascript, css, phantomjs

I need to pass form data in UnCSS to login to my websites access controlled area however I cannot seem to find any examples on how to do this. I know that UnCSS uses PhantomJS and I have managed to, very easily, get PhantomJS to do this, however I can't see how to do it was UnCSS. With PhantomJS you just do:

```
page.open(loginPage, 'post', loginDetails, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to login');
    } else {
        console.log('Login successful');
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you get any way of how to access login controlled area yet ?

Comment: Yes, I used a PhantomJS script to login and scrap the pages to HTML file in a local folder and then used these files in the UnCSS script as the source. Did it using the Gulp task running with gulp-phantom and gulp-uncss.

Answer (score 2):

There is really no way of doing this easily and automated. To achieve automation, you would need to extend [UnCSS](https://github.com/giakki/uncss) with a "prefix" script which is run before the actual page is unCSSed (?).

An easier way of extending would be to let unCSS use a cookies file. You would then create a simple PhantomJS or CasperJS script to login and generate that cookies file for you (`--cookies-file=cookies.txt`).

The other easy, but not automated way would be to save the page in your browser of choice (with all resources) and let UnCSS do its work.

Comment: UnCSS already does what you are saying, you can pass it multiple URL's and it does browse through those URL's and creates a single stylesheet from it. I already have this working for my public facing website, it is just the login I'm having a problem with.

Comment: Thanks, I somehow missed that part about an array of files, two paragraphs removed, one added.

Comment: This would be an option, however I'm now exploring another idea which has come to be. With PhantomJS I should be able to get the HTML for the pages in the "members", save these to a file and then use then pass the files into UnCSS instead of giving it a list of URL. So, basically get PhantomJS to crawl the site first and then use the crawled with the UnCSS process. That way I think I can automate it all via Gulp. I will post back a solution if I manage to get it going.

Comment: I've looked through the examples for PhantomJS, but haven't found a script which would actually help you scrape everything. Note that you have to essentially make a local copy. So will have to not only download every resource that is requested, you also have to replace the (partial) resource in the page, before you save it. This may be a challenging endeavor

Comment: All you need to UnCSS to work is the HTML and you get this from PhantomJS easily with the page.content variable. You can then easily write this to a file using the fs library. I already pretty much have it working, having only spent about 1 hour on it.

Comment: Which means that every resource has a full URL on your page and not just a partial like `<link href="/path/to/style.css" ...>` and `<img src="img.png">`